# How to stay within a 'instance' using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently learning JavaScript/JQuery, but have an issue at work that I'm running into.

I've assigned a class of 'question' to an`<a>`tag, and 'answer' to a`<div>`. When a user clicks on the question, the answer will slide down. However, the problem I'm running into is that when they click on a `<a href="#" class="question">`, all of the `<div class="answer">`'s are displayed.

How can I make it so that only one .answer for it's parent .question is displayed when clicked?

Here is my HTML:

```
<li class="question"><a href="#">Question 1</a>
<div class="answer"><p>This is answer for question 1</p></div></li>
<li class="question"><a href="#">Question 2</a>
<div class="answer"><p>This is answer for question 2</p></div></li>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('div.answer').hide();
    $('li.question').click(function() {
      $('div.answer').slideDown('fast');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

and the site is: http://topactioninvestments.com/faq/

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Comment: _"I've assigned a class of 'question' to an `<a>` tag"_ - No you haven't, you've assigned the class to the containing `<li>`. Also, the `<div>` for the answer is redundant: why not use `<p class="answer">`? (Surely you don't need the `<div>` _and_ the `<p>`?)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('li.question').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('div.answer').slideToggle('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you typically want to do is have each unit within a container element. An example would be a `div` or other tag. Say your HTML looked like this:

```
<div class="qa">
  <div class="question">What is 2+2?</div>
  <div class="answer">4</div>
</div>
```

Then you could do:

```
$('.question').click(function(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);
  target
    .closest('.qa')
    .find('.answer')
      .show();
});
```

Your markup for each question and answer looks like this:

```
<li>
  <a><strong>Why do you not just sell these option contracts?</strong></a>
  <div class="answer"><p>This is a test</p></div>
</li>
```

For this markup, this JavaScript would work:

```
$('li').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).find('.answer').show();
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLRkE/)

Answer (score 0):

Give every answer element an unique **id** attribute and add a **data-answer** attribute to the the the question that references the unique **question**.

The do the following.

```
$('li.question').click(function(e) {
    $($(this).data("answer")).show();
});
```

To clarify with the relevant html.

```
<li class="question" data-answer="#answer-42">...</li>
<div class="answer id="answer-42">....</div>
```